# Complex Text Parsing - Please Help Figure Out

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I'm rather poor in algorithm design and have a complex problem - please take a look. I'm currently working in Java/Groovy.

I've got some text that looks like this:

```
AAAAA  
AAAAA
CCCCC
any stuff here  
111  
any stuff here  
AAAAA  
stuff  
AAAAA  
stuff  
AAAAA  

BBBBB  
stuff  
222  
stuff  
BBBBB
```

My challenge is to grab all the strings that are in the format of AAAAA stuff 111 stuff AAAAA, without grabbing any surrounding text. You can see that there are multiple AAAAA in the string, but I must only grab the ones closest to the 111s and 222s, and then do this for all strings of this type.

My regular expressions (not working) look like this:

```
/(\w{8}|\w{11}).*?(\w{3}).*?\1/
```

I've been playing around with a bunch of them and they either grab too much text or perform too slowly... if anyone has an idea of what I should be using for this type of problem, please let me know.

Edit: These are what I am trying to match:

```
AAAAA
CCCCC
any stuff here  
111  
any stuff here  
AAAAA
```

and

```
BBBBB  
stuff  
222  
stuff  
BBBBB
```

I'd say this is pretty much like parsing improperly tagged XML.
Anyway, thanks for looking.

Comment: Could please show us more clearly which parts of the example input you want to have matched?

Comment: give some sample output for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I added examples to the original post.

Comment: do the `AAAAA` really need to be the same character? or could it be anything that appears twice? and does it have to be exactly 5 characters?

Comment: No, not the same character... they can be any \w{5}. Sane with the sequence of 3 chars. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Chris - Regex is, as the name implies, used for matching/forming regular expressions, not detecting proximity of matches. You are mixing up two completely different things.

Comment: In real world what `AAAAA`, `BBBBB`, `111` and `222` can be? Show us some real example not blah-blah....

Comment: A friend just suggested that I can break this into lines and parse it by iterating through until I find the '111', moving forward to find the closest "closing tag", then moving backward to find the "opening tag". I'm going to try this and come back.

Comment: Any `\w{5}` is also `_1_Ac` for example. Is such word the only in row then?

Comment: There is junk possible but it can be filtered, so we can assume it is the only in the row.

Comment: TheLima, what do you suggest I use instead? Some kind of scanner?

Comment: Do you just want the text on the lines either side of a line of numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex pattern

```
(?s)\b(\w{5})\b(?:(?!\1).)*?\b\w{3}\b(?:(?!\1).)*?\1
```